# Display multiple app screens at the same time

Tags: applications, screen

Is it possible to display multiple apps on the screen?

Normally, apps load fullscreen, and app-switching switches between fullscreen apps. Is it possible for an app to use only half of the screen and another one to use the other half?

Comment: You could use [Floating Apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lwi.android.flappsfull&hl=en)

Comment: [Android N will support multi-window](http://developer.android.com/preview/features/multi-window.html) (if your device get it...)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Samsung phone, there is a split screen option. I personally have not used it, so you would have to look into it. The option is not available as stand, no.

There are some third party ROMs, that are capable of doing it but you would need to root your phone.  Have a look at the link below. I had a quick look out on the web and found this:
[How to Get Multi-Window Multitasking on Any Android Phone or Tablet](http://www.howtogeek.com/189345/how-to-get-multi-window-multitasking-on-any-android-phone-or-tablet/)

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies. For further hints, please see: [How do I write a good answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).